# Is it possible to reprogram the physical button functions on Huawei smartwatch?

Tags: wear-os

I would like to use the physical button of Android Wear smartwatches to initiate a call on mobile phone (after pressing it multiple times)

I want to build an app which, after pressing the button 4 times, would initiate a fake call (with vibro function) on the cell phone.

Is it possible to do this, aren't these button functions reserved by manufacturer?

Comment: I'm not putting this as an Answer, because I can't definitively say that it's **not** possible... but I don't think that what you're asking for is achievable. If you already have an Activity in the foreground on the device, it's usually possible to intercept hardware events. But to remap the button when your code isn't already running? Probably not.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose an app needs to be running all the time then and waiting for hardware button press sequence, right? I suppose it will be hard on battery consumption, will it? How do I estimate how much battery consumption in percents this app would reduce?

Comment: I don't think that there's a way to estimate battery usage ahead of time like that. You'd need to prototype it and measure the effect, ideally on a couple of different devices.